# Pinescript failed to show a plot

Tags: pine-script-v4

I am not sure why this scripts doesnt produce line plot

```
/@version=4
study("Momentum Measures", shorttitle="Local Momentum", overlay=true)

//Inputs lookback
Periodlookback  = input(4, "Length", minval=1, group = "Length")

momentum_mean(length) =>
    mean_open = sma(open, length)
    mean_close = sma(close, length)
    min_open = lowest(open, length)
    max_open = highest(open, length)
    min_close = lowest(close, length)
    max_close = highest(close, length)
    adj_range_open = (((max_open + min_open + mean_open) / 3) - mean_open)
    adj_range_close = (((max_close + min_close + mean_close) / 3) - mean_close)
    abs(adj_range_open - adj_range_close)

//Plot Momentum
timeframe_momentum = momentum_mean(Periodlookback)
plot(timeframe_momentum, title = "Local Momentum", style = plot.style_line, color = color.white, linewidth = 2)
```

The value only displayed in the right side of the indicators, but no line-plot at all, please help!

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I need is an `overlay=false`, `overlay=true` makes the chart in 1 with the bar charts, and i had to change and reuse the indicators to finally show the plot